# Using DirectX Effect11 with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: directx, visual-studio-2012

I recently updated to Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I was programming previously with DirectX 11 June 2010 SDK and want to continue to do so using Visual Studio 2012. However, I discovered that VS2012 comes with its own DirectX SDK (in Windows Kit 8.0) and I've been trying to migrate my code using the newer versions of d3d11. Everything went fine until I try to use effect files in my project (.fx files). I had to compile the Effects11 Sample in the DirectX SDK using VS2012 and link the lib file in my project. That went fine too. However, when I compile my project the function `D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory` returns a `E_NOINTERFACE error (no such interface is supported)`. Can anyone tell me why is that? Note that I'm using the d3d11.lib from the Windows Kit and the `d3dx11.lib` from the DirectX SDK. Perhaps I shouldn't mix them? However, everything else works fine when I mix them, except for the effect file creation.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I don't know if this is helpful but just so you know, if I add an additional library directory in the project settings of `"DirectXSDKInstallPath\lib\x86\"` it works. Why is that? Does it mean I'm using the older version of the libraries? This will give a ton of warnings about redefined headers in winerror.h

Comment: "Visual Studio 2012" is not a programming language; it's a development tool that works with several different languages. What specific language are you using? What is the specific code that's failing?

Comment: Sorry, should have made myself clearer. I'm using C++ as a programming language. The specific code is the function D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory (as vini kindly highlighted for me). It returns a "no interface found" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3DX Library has been deprecated for the newest version of DirectX 11 (Windows 8). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172965(v=vs.85).aspx

Effects are now handled a different way. You can program your own library to load effects or use DirectX Tool Kit (DirectXTK): http://directxtk.codeplex.com/

Microsoft has recommended this tool kit on their web site, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx for more information.

Comment: Ok, DirectXTK seems to provide a lot of functionalities. Btw, if anyone is interested, I decided to handle everything with separate shaders

Answer (score 1):

Effect11 has moved to https://fx11.codeplex.com/, you need to compile it and link yourself.

DirectXTK does not provide the effect11 interface, but only simplified effects

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by d3d library conflicts.

Make sure what d3d libraries you are using.Because there are 2 different d3d libraries.

One in DXSDK_DIR\Lib\x86 or \x64,and one in c:\program files(x86?)\Microsoft SDKs.

If you are using DXSDK, then pass $(DXSDK_DIR)Include $(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86  ahead of Microsoft SDKs' includes,libs directory in the Include directories and Library directories fields  respectively.

Comment: With VS 2012/VS 2013 since they use the Windows 8.x SDK, it's important that you *reverse* this traditional order and put the Microsoft SDKs include/lib paths *before* the $(DXSDK_DIR) paths. This is covered on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) in some detail.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous version of Direct3D, the effects framework worked out of the box once you linked with the D3D10 library. In Direct3D 11, the effects framework has been moved to the D3DX library, and you have to include a separate header file (d3dx11Effect.h) and link with a separate library (D3DX11Effects.libfor release builds and D3DX11EffectsD.libfor debug builds).

Furthermore, in Direct3D 11, they give you the full source code for the effects library code (DirectX SDK\Samples\C++ \Effects11). Thus, you could modify the effects framework for your own needs. In this book, we will only be using the effects framework as is, without modification. In order to use the library, you need to first build the  Effects11project in both release and debug mode to generate the D3DX11Effects.lib and D3DX11EffectsD.libfiles; you will only need to do this once unless the effects framework is updated (e.g., a new version of the DirectX SDK may update these files, so you may want to rebuild the .lib files to get the latest version). The  d3dx11Effect.h header file can be found in  DirectX SDK\Samples\C++\Effects11\Inc.

For our sample projects, we place the  d3dx11Effect.h, D3DX11EffectsD.lib, and D3DX11Effects.libfiles in the Commondirectory that all of our projects share code from (see the “Introduction” for a description of the sample project organization).